# Crystal Oscillator

Tags: oscillator, datasheet, crystal, data, information

What are the markings mean on this crystal that I found on a motherboard? Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first letter **A** signifies it is made by [Abracon](http://www.abracon.com/)

the next part **24.0** indicates it is a 24 Mhz crystal.

The **F** indicates the month the crystal was made, letters A to J are possible, this crystal was manufactured in June.

The **7** is the last digit of the year it was manufactured in. So this was likely made in 2007.

The last letter **K** is an internal code used for tracing the product (such as which machine or facility it was made at).